# cloning bitcoin MAX_MONEY not working

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

I have changed the amount of coins to be mined, to be 1000 but looks did not work, I have already 8000 coins mined, can someone explain why it is not working?

**main.h**

```
static const int64 MAX_MONEY = 1000 * COIN;  //coin limit

static const int COINBASE_MATURITY = 2;

return dPriority > COIN * 1000 / 250; //after 10 blocks the dificulty will reajust
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static const int64 MAX_MONEY = 1000 * COIN;  //coin limit
```

Maximum amount (in satoshi) allowed anywhere (in the whole network). COIN is equal to 10^8
This is NOT the total amount of coins which your software is going to produce.

```
static const int COINBASE_MATURITY = 2;
```

Coinbase transactions cannot be spent before this number of confirms (i.e. 2)

Comment: thanks a lot bro, but I have no money :) I am learning this , to try get a better life for me, family  and my daughter , I just lost my job. could tell me where I can insert the max coin limit? because as I see it is there.

Comment: Please don't use answers as job ads.